# weighting not works in 'aov' function of R

Tags: r, anova, weighted

I have got in trouble with implementing weighted dataset by `aov` function in R. 
For example my dataset "data_file" has target var "Y", and four independent var named (treat, V1 ,V2, V3). 
Assuming: 
V1(2 groups) & treat(3 groups) --> categorical, 
V2 and v3 --> continuous.

I want to check baseline comparisons of independent variables among treat groups.
I ran `aov` test for this purpose,example:

```
base_V2_aov <- aov(data_file$V2 ~ data_file$treat)
base_V2_anov <- anova(base_V2_aov)
base_V2
```

It worked and showed significant difference of V2 among "treat" group but other variables were non significant, then i decided to weight my data based on V2 and run `aov` test in weighted data.

I used `mnps` function in `Twang` package for weighting.

```
mnps.data <- mnps(treat ~ V2, data_file, estimand = "ATE", stop-method = "es.mean", n.trees=5000, varbose = F)
data_file$ weight <- get.weights(mnps.data, stop.method = "es.mean")
```

I have read in one stackoverflow answer that `survey` packages does not support weighting for one-way ANOVA test, but `aov` function does. 
So i ran this code:

```
base_V2_aov <- aov(data_file$V2 ~ data_file$trea, weights(data_file$weight))
base_V2_anov <- anova(base_V2_aov)
print(base_V2_anov)
```

It showes an error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I tried :

```
base_V2_aov <- aov(data_file$V2 ~ data_file$trea, weights(weight))
```

It did not find object "weight"

I also checked this :

```
base_V2_aov <- aov(data_file$V2 ~ data_file$trea, weights(data_file))
```

It did not show error, but the results were exactly the same as without weighting(i expected to change base on significant difference without weighting)

I want to know what is the appropriate "object" for weights in `aov` function?

Comment: I believe you should use the `weights` argument.  Like `weights = data_file$weights`.  Have you tried that?  Right now you appear to be attempting to use a `weights()` function, which you are passing to `data` (the second argument of the `aov()` function).

Comment: @aosmith , Actually i thought i have tried this. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you should use:
`weight = your weighting variable` in the `aov` arguments.
I replicate something like your dataset, and after using above code the results of the comparisons between groups were different which showed that weighting method had worked.